Situation with Artemov's paper?
Artemov's paper on Goedel's theorem has been on the arxiv since 2019.  There was a (less than fully friendly) discussion of this on FoM.  At stackexchange, I found only a brief mention at this MSE post.  Artemov's paper has apparently not yet been published in a refereed venue (which could lead to inferences that I proactively ask the users to avoid).
Could somebody knowledgeable about the material comment on the upshot with this paper, sticking to logic and expert opinion (and avoiding snide remarks)?
I just became aware of an update posted a month ago:

Artemov, Sergei.  Serial Properties, Selector Proofs, and the Provability of Consistency.  https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.12272v1


I voted to close, because MO is not the right venue for discussing correctness of preprints.

I think MO is the right venue for questions like this.

Look @Carl Artemov is a fine logician (in fact one of the best one we have) and has  a sterling reputation.  I don't want to compare Artemov to Perelman, but would you also argue that MO is not the right venue for discussing Perelman's proof of the Poincare conjecture because his work only appeared in the form of arxiv preprints?

@MikhailKatz I think there’s precedence for asking questions about specific parts or claims in a preprint, but not “is this preprint correct or not?”, regardless of the strength of the mathematician. Cf. the recent questions on abc, which I think was handled well.

@Carl, the question does not reduce to "is this preprint correct or not".  Users mostly agree that the technical claims are correct; the issue is the interpretation of the technical results, where there happens to be a spectrum of opinions according to the answers received.

I think this question is ok for MO, but could be improved by saying exactly what you are looking for in terms of answers, rather than just request users to "comment on the upshot" of the paper. As is, together with the focus on the publication status of the paper in the first paragraph, it sort of comes across as though you are most interested in whether the paper will be published.

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda I agree with Mikhail Katz that he's not asking about the correctness of the preprint, or at least not of the correctness of the mathematical portion of it. The mathematical portion is uncontroversial, as far as I can tell. The implicit question is about the unconventional philosophical conclusions Artemov tries to draw. I suppose one could take the point of view that the philosophical aspect is too "subjective and argumentative" for MO, but Katz does at least try to urge the respondent to write civilly.

@MikhailKatz Regarding Perelman, I am reminded of Shing-Tung Yau's doubts about Perelman's proof, which a lot of people also wanted to close. Obviously, I thought that question should stay open, but I can sympathize with the desire for MO to stick strictly to mathematical claims themselves, rather than the "meta-question" of what various people think about mathematical claims.

I agree with @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda (comment) that the question as written does not seem appropriate for MO, and so voted to close yesterday. I agree with @‍SamHopkins (comment) that the question could be improved, and made appropriate for MO, by saying exactly what was being asked.  I finally agree with @‍TimothyChow that the more detailed question outlined in a comment is appropriate for MO, and so retracted my close vote.

Not relevant to this exact formulation, but this seems spiritually related to Andrew Boucher's "Arithmetic Without the Successor Axiom". That system has models for all initial segments of the naturals, and the model which only contains 0 can be proven consistent by contradiction (pp.107), implying that the theory is consistent. The practical drawback of that system is that all proofs need to assume the existence of a satisfactorily large number, and bookkeeping that each proof step only invokes numbers less than this maximum.

What "FoM" means? (I hate acronyms).

@MatemáticosChibchas: "FoM" = Foundations of Mathematics listserv. See https://cs.nyu.edu/mailman/listinfo/fom

Foundations of Mathematics is now here: https://lists.ugent.be/wws/info/fom but the Artemov discussions is archived at the old site.

@MikhailKatz Where can I find the (less than fully friendly) discussion of this on FoM?

@JoelAdler, It's at the link provided by Sam Hopkins above.  The discussion took place in march and april of '19.

@JoelAdler It's probably the thread that begins here: https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2019-March/021436.html

@ Michael Katz & The Amplitwist Thank you!

The essential issue is the same as one that has been discussed many times here on MO, for example here and here. Consider the following string $S$.
$$(\exists x \exists y \exists z : xxx + yyy - zzz = 114) \vee (\exists x \exists y \exists z : xxx - yyy - zzz = 114) \vee (\exists x \exists y \exists z : xxx + yyy + zzz = 114)$$
Let me now make a claim.

Claim. If there is a valid mathematical proof, using only the mathematical assumptions that are formalized by the axioms of PA along with classical logic, that 114 is the sum of three cubes, then there exists a formal PA-proof of $S$.

(EDIT: With hindsight, I probably should have used $\neg S$ rather than $S$ as my example, because $\neg S$ is closer in flavor to Con(PA). The choice between $S$ and $\neg S$ doesn't change the point I'm making, but judging from some of the questions I've received, $\neg S$ would have made for a clearer example.)
The above Claim is not a strictly mathematical claim, because it refers to the informal notion of a "valid mathematical proof," which is not a strictly mathematical entity. By contrast, formal PA-proofs are mathematical entities. In effect, the Claim is asserting that, in a certain important sense, formal PA-proofs "capture" the informal notion of "valid mathematical proof" and $S$ "captures" the assertion that 114 is the sum of three cubes. The Claim is somewhat akin to the Church–Turing thesis, in that it asserts that a pre-existing informal concept is adequately captured by a precise mathematical concept.
I happen to believe the Claim, and so does almost everyone. Indeed, it's hard to see why one would study PA-proofs if one did not believe the Claim. But you are not compelled to believe the Claim. You are free to deny it. In particular, even if someone manages to prove that $S$ is independent of PA, you could still insist that it remains an open question whether "114 is a sum of three cubes" admits a valid mathematical proof using only the mathematical assumptions formalized by the axioms of PA along with classical logic. In effect, you would be claiming that $S$ fails in some way to be an accurate formalization of "114 is the sum of three cubes."
Because the statement that "114 is the sum of three cubes" is so simple, it is hard to imagine someone seriously arguing against the Claim. However, suppose we now replace "114 is the sum of three cubes" with "PA is consistent" and we replace $S$ with the formal string that is typically given the name "Con(PA)." Since Con(PA) is such a complicated string, and consistency is such a notoriously confusing concept, it's now easier to imagine someone denying the analogous Claim, and maintaining that Con(PA) somehow fails to "capture" the consistency of PA in the sense that the Claim asserts. The late philosopher Michael Detlefsen was perhaps the best-known denialist.
Similarly, Artemov is a denialist in this sense. Artemov, of course, does not deny the truth of Gödel's second incompleteness theorem. But Gödel's 2nd theorem tells us only that Con(PA) is formally unprovable in PA. Artemov denies that we can infer that the consistency of PA cannot be proved from the mathematical assumptions that are formalized by the axioms of PA. To defend this contrarian position, Artemov shows that PA can prove some things that seem awfully close to asserting the consistency of PA. I won't go into the details of Artemov's paper, but here is a classical fact: for any finite subset of the axioms of PA (remember that PA contains an axiom schema and hence has infinitely many axioms), PA can prove that that finite set of axioms is consistent. That sure seems close to proving consistency, doesn't it? After all, if there is an inconsistency in PA, only finitely many axioms will be needed to derive that inconsistency. Whichever specific list of finitely many axioms you might single out on suspicion of yielding an inconsistency, PA proves that that particular list of axioms is consistent. Maybe you feel that's close enough to "PA proves its own consistency"? Or if not, maybe the results that Artemov proves will strike you as convincing.
In short, I would say that there's nothing particularly novel about Artemov's results. It has been clear to experts from the very beginning that this type of denialism is a philosophical option you can take, so certainly that's not new. Personally, I don't find Con(PA) to be an inadequate expression of the consistency of PA any more than I find $S$ to be an inadequate expression of "114 is the sum of three cubes," and neither do most people. But your mileage may vary.

Consistency is the property of not every sentence being a formal theorem. Why is this a "notoriously confusing concept" ?

@ChristianRemling Once you start throwing Rosser sentences and nonstandard models into the mix, not to mention the fact that strictly speaking Con(PA) is a sentence about arithmetic rather than about syntax directly, there is plenty of room for people to get confused.

That would be relevant if you had written "$\textrm{Con(PA)}$ is a notoriously confusing concept" (which is probably what you meant). My (trivial, admittedly) comment was that consistency of a theory is one of the easiest mathematical definitions you'll ever meet and thoroughly unconfusing.

@ChristianRemling: Consistency is a technically simple definition, but it’s an empirical fact that people often get very confused about it (even before its formal coding into arithmetic). Maybe it shouldn’t be so confusing, but in practice it is.

What a great answer.  I realize this comment adds nothing, but my upvote seemed insufficient to express my thanks.

"Denialist" and "contrarian" are the kind of terms that I asked users here not to use.

@TimothyChow: could you contrast the claim with the similar sounding claim "if 114 is the sum of three cubes then there is a PA proof of $S$". Is there a difference?

@MikhailKatz "Denialist" is in no way a "snide remark" or an "inference", it is a descriptive term. Artemov denies (hence denialist) that the formal sentence Con(PA) captures the whole mathematical concept of "consistency of arithmetics".

@MikhailKatz I agree with Marco Capitani. In his paper, Artemov himself emphasizes that he is taking a contrarian position, as you can see from his exhortations to the community to change their minds about a conventionally accepted belief. And what is contrarian about his view? Precisely that he denies the Claim. Someone who denies is a denialist. It would be misleading to suggest that Artemov is just doing math as usual and not making any controversial claims.

@AndrejBauer Technically, I should probably have phrased the Claim to also say, "If there is a mathematical proof that 114 is not the sum of three cubes...then there is a PA_proof of $\neg S$." But I didn't want to clutter the Claim with too much verbiage.

"for any finite subset of the axioms of PA, PA can prove that that finite set of axioms is consistent." A very important caveat is that PA can't prove the statement "every finite subset of PA is consistent". Rather, you need a different proof for each finite subset, and in particular this requires doing meta-mathematics over infinitely many statements, not just working in PA.

@TimothyChow: thanks, that clears up things a bit. Still, I said "144 is the sum" (truth) and you said "there is a mathematical proof" (provability in some sort of non-formal sense). Is this supposed to be significant difference? (I am just trying to understand what is being said.)

@AndrejBauer Yes, there is a difference, which is clearer in the case of "114 is not the sum of three cubes." Certainly, we don't expect in general that if 114 is not the sum of three cubes, then we'll be able to prove that fact, in PA or any other system. What we do expect is that if someone publishes a (human-readable) proof that 114 is not the sum of three cubes, and says that they used only first-order induction, then we'll be able to produce a formal proof of $\neg S$ from PA in a proof assistant (barring some serious mistake in the original paper that was initially overlooked).

@AndrejBauer I believe this is the best way to make sense of Artemov's claims. Since Artemov accepts Goedel's 2nd theorem, and that PA is consistent, how can it still be possible to prove the consistency of PA in PA? The only way out is for there to be some mismatch between Con(PA) and "PA is consistent," allowing for there to be some kind of proof that PA is consistent that does not translate into a formal proof of Con(PA).

"Someone who denies is a denialist." I deny that moon is cheese, hence I guess I'm a "denialist", too. Are you? The term carries a negative tone and is used to label people. We should be able to offer different perspectives and even controversial views without being labeled. Many great ideas in science were controversial when first presented. Label the claim if you will, not the human behind.

If Artemov denies that a statement like $S$ is talking about the number 114 being a sum of cubes, then how does anything stated and proved in PA prove anything about the real world?

The 114 example is a sigma sentence concerning which PA is complete, i.e., proves it if it is true. The consistency formula Con(PA) is Pi_1, and PA is notoriously incomplete w.r.t. such sentences. However, if Con(PA) were informally provable by means of PA, there would be a formal derivation of it in PA. The problem is that Con(PA) does not have an informal proof by means of PA, which makes the reasoning above about Con(PA) purely hypothetical. The problem with the Unprovability of consistency is that there are consistency formalizations not equivalent to Con(PA) in PA.

@AndrejBauer and others. I reiterate. The principal (and fundamental) difference between the "114" example and Con(PA) is that "114" is a $\Sigma_1$ sentence, and PA is complete w.r.t. such sentences. This observation justifies  Claim: if there is ANY valid mathematical proof of "114", "114" is true and, by $\Sigma_1$-completeness, is provable in PA. In contrast, Con(PA) is a $\Pi_1$ sentence concerning which PA is incomplete, meaning that Con(PA) may have valid mathematical proof outside PA but be unprovable in PA, which is precisely the case. So comparing "114" with Con(PA) is void.

@SergeiArtemov I don't understand your point. Suppose I replace "114 is the sum of three cubes" with "114 is not the sum of three cubes." Doesn't that address your objection? If so, then just "search and replace" 114 with $\neg$114 everywhere.

@TimothyChow. S and Con(PA) are not connected "at all." We must present proof within PA limits that "PA is consistent" implies Con(PA). The first step is the default Goedel numbering, which translates the definition of PA consistency, "any derivation D is consistent" into "any NUMERAL n does not contain inconsistency," which is equivalent to the series "n is consistent" for n=0,1,2,..., called Con^S(PA), no meta-assumptions about PA are needed. Since Con^S(PA) does not imply Con(PA) in PA, Con(PA) is strictly stronger than "PA is consistent." Which of these steps is difficult?

@SergeiArtemov: I think that's clear. At a purely technical level, is this more than just the difference between $\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ and "for every (external) finite subset $S$ of axioms of $\mathsf{PA}$, $\mathsf{PA}$ proves that $S$ is consistent"? Right? The dilemma is really meta-mathematical, namely which formalization of "$\mathsf{PA}$ is consistent" should be considered the relevant one?

@SergeiArtemov My question has nothing to do with the consistency of PA. I am addressing your objection to "114". You say that the problem with "114" is that it is a $\Sigma_1$ sentence. But everything I'm saying about "114" applies equally to "$\neg$114", which is not $\Sigma_1$. So your stated objection to "114" evaporates. Right? Again, I'm not talking about the consistency of PA at all.

@TimothyChow If you haven't already, you should take a look at my exchange with Sergei in the comments to Peter's answer (starting here), since I think it gets at the same basic issue. Sergei's view seems to be that the standard formalization of Lagrange's theorem in PA (as a universally quantified sentence) is not correct/adequate (he says "quick and dirty"), and that it is only useful because it is in fact provable and stronger than the "honest" formalization as a scheme.

@AlexKruckman Thank you; I had indeed missed that exchange. It is illuminating. Since the provability of "$\neg$114" is not known, it's an obvious next example to consider after Lagrange's four-square theorem. If I understand correctly, "$\neg$114" is only a "quick and dirty" formalization and not an "honest" formalization of "114 is not the sum of three cubes." Is that your understanding as well?

@TimothyChow. I dismiss the whole story in your post that connects "144" to Con(PA): there is no visible connection. Since "144" is irrelevant, with your kind permission, I will no longer discuss it in the context of PA consistency. I remain open to discussing the provability of consistency problems. Thank you for your genuine interest in this matter.

@SergeiArtemov Okay, but in your discussion with Alex Kruckman, you seemed to accept that "every integer is the sum of four squares" is relevant to the discussion, right? So "every sufficiently large integer is the sum of four nonnegative cubes" should also be relevant? That statement is currently unproved, so are you saying that the usual formalization of "every sufficiently large integer is the sum of four nonnegative cubes" is not "honest" and is only "quick and dirty"?

@TimothyChow. Alex Kruckman asked a different question and got the appropriate answer. As for the whole picture of the "quick-and-dirty" use of PA quantifiers to approximate quantifiers over numerals, please check my recent reply to Alex Kruckman, starting with "An in-depth answer." You are welcome to join this meaningful discussion on PA quantifiers vs. numeral quantifiers.

Isn’t he saying that the PA version of the statement is true in models with nonstandard numbers and so it stronger than the statement that it is true for standard numbers? From my very naive, non-logician perspective, I think his idea is that the latter is sufficient and is trying to formalize that notion.

Disclaimer: I am not an expert in the proof theory of arithmetic.  However, I don’t think one needs to be to assess this paper.  It is admirably clear, well-written, and well-referenced, so it’s not onerous to verify that its precise mathematical claims and proofs all seem perfectly correct, and not particularly controversial.  However, its main extra-mathematical claim, that these results can be viewed of a proof of consistency of PA, formalisable in PA, seems unconvincing, and its arguments for this claim are not I think particularly novel (though Artemov presents them unusually clearly).
The main precise mathematical claims are (very slightly paraphrased):

for each $n$, PA proves the statement “$n$ does not code a proof of $\bot$ in PA” (which we abbreviate as “$\lnot (n \colon \bot)$”);
moreover, this is witnessed by a primitive recursive function taking each $n$ to the proof of “$\lnot (n \colon \bot)$”;
these two facts can themselves be proven in PA.

The first two facts are fairly straightforwardly provable using standard techniques from the proof theory of arithmetic, in several ways (Artemov uses truth-definitions for $\Sigma_n$ formulas); and the fact that PA is a sufficient metatheory for them (indeed, small fragments such as PRA suffice) is also standard, as discussed in e.g. the answers of this old MO question.  There is nothing controversial or questionable about any of this.
The tenuous step is when Artemov argues that this can be seen a proof of consistency of PA, within PA.  The stretch becomes clear when we carefully break the claim down to definitions.  “PA is consistent” means “there is no proof of contradiction in PA”, i.e. “there is no $n$ which codes a proof of $\bot$ in PA”, or equivalently “for each $n$, $n$ does not code a PA-proof of $\bot$”.  So just taking things to mean what they’re defined to, a proof of “PA is consistent” in PA should be a proof of “for all $n$, $\lnot (n \colon \bot)$” in PA.
Artemov argues that since for each $n$ we can prove “$\lnot (n \colon \bot)$” in PA, and we can prove that schematic-provability using PA as metatheory, we can view this overall as a proof of the consistency of PA in PA.  But note that the quantifier “for each $n$” has been moved to between provability claim.  So we have proved in the inner-PA a schema of statements, and then in the outer-PA, we can assert the provability of that schema as a single statement.  But we have not presented a proof in either copy of PA of a single statement that can be read as “PA is consistent”.  In the inner PA, we have proven a schema of statments about specific finite derivations in PA.  In the outer PA, we’ve proven a fact about PA which certainly can’t be read as “PA is consistent”, since we could prove the same schema for an inconsistent theory of arithmetic.  Artemov’s argument that this can be called a proof in PA of consistency of PA reminds me of an old joke: “If you call a dog’s tail a leg, how many legs does a dog have?” “Four — calling the tail a leg doesn’t mean it is one.”
The parametric proof of this scheme certainly shows that PA comes very close to proving its own consistency.  A similar argument for ZF can be given by for instance the reflection theorem — that for any finite list of axioms of ZF, ZF proves there’s some $V_\alpha$ which models them (and hence that they’re consistent).  Most textbook presentations of these reflection principles that I’ve seen discuss this point explicitly — they note that these results bring the theory very close to proving its own consistency, but on close inspection, don’t quite prove it.
A piece of background worth noting here (a point which iirc I learned from Timothy Chow on this site) is that Hilbert’s consistency programme was not just to prove consistency of arithmetic within arithmetic — that would prima facie be a rather weak result, since an inconsistent theory would still prove its own consistency.  Hilbert’s hope was to prove the consistency of some kind of set theory from some theory of arithmetic — justifying a more abstract theory by means of a more self-evident one, which would be a genuinely valuable result.  The point of Gödel’s theorem was showing that not even the much weaker result was attainable — let alone the stronger result Hilbert had hoped for.  So while reflection-principle arguments show that PA and ZF come tantalisingly close to proving their own consistency — close enough that a little good rhetoric can stretch tenuously across the gap — they don’t come at all so close to Hilbert’s actual dream, of proving consistency of set theory from arithmetic; and by Gödel they can’t, since finite fragments of set theory suffice to prove consistency of PA.

Unless I'm missing something, there's no need to appeal to reflection in Artemov's claim. Consider the function $p$ which on input $n$ behaves as follows. First, we check whether $n$ is a PA-proof of $\perp$. If it is not, then $p$ outputs a formal proof verifying this. If it is, though, then we can explicitly find a slightly larger number $m$ which is a PA-proof of "$n$ is not a PA-proof of $\perp$," using the proof coded by $n$ together with ex falso, and $p$ outputs that $m$.  This $p$ is primitive recursive, and all of the above is verifiable in PA. Or have I made a mistake here?

Certainly the appeal to reflection is a "better" schematic proof, but I see no reason why what I've described doesn't fit Artemov's criteria for a schematic proof. And this seems to weaken his claim that schematic provability of consistency of PA inside PA has some foundational value, irrespective of his concerns about the second incompleteness theorem.

@NoahSchweber: I completely agree; have edited to reflect that point.

@EmilJeřábek: I don’t see that?  To show we can schematically prove in PA the consistency-schema for ZF just by $\Sigma_1$-completeness, for instance, we need to assume (externally) that ZF actually is consistent, don’t we?  But to schematically-prove in PA the consistency-schema for PA (either as Artemov does, or as Noah describes) we don’t need to assume PA is consistent.  Generally, if a theory T of arithmetic can schematically-prove the consistency-schema for a theory T', then Con(T) => Con(T'); so if T' has higher consistency strength than T, this will need a strong metatheory.

@EmilJeřábek: in general I’m quite happy to accept that ZF is consistent — but when we’re talking about any kind of consistency proofs, it seems important to be explicit about any such assumptions, externally as well as internally!

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine You have misstated Artemov's definition; the key property of the p.r. function in (2) should itself be PA-provable. This leads to a less trivial situation. See Definition 1 on page 9 of Artemov's paper.

Since the definition in Artemov's paper is apparently different, I deleted my comments above so as not to proliferate the confusion.

@NoahSchweber: Thanks for pointing out that I’d omitted that part of Artemov’s claims — edited to include and discuss it explicitly.  I’d left it out originally since it’s again a very standard fact — that the metatheory required for any of these arguments is very minimal and finitistic.

@EmilJeřábek: I’m sorry you deleted your comments — your arguments in them still fit just fine with the third component of Artemov’s definition, modulo being explicit about consistency assumptions in the metatheory-PA as I mentioned in my original reply.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Thanks for editing the answer! Re: Emil's comments, I don't recall them perfectly but I'm not sure they do continue to hold; see e.g. the difference between his answer and my answer (both of which are correct) at abo's linked question. The third point is absolutely critical for the general behavior of the schematic provability relation.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine. Your quote: "So just taking things to mean what they're defined to, a proof of "PA is consistent" in PA should be a proof of "for all $n$, $\neg (n:\bot)$." Reply: Try to justify your conclusion that Con(PA) is equivalent to "PA is consistent" inside PA. You will need references to the standard model (outside PA), which indicates that Con(PA) is not equivalent in PA to "PA is consistent" (this can be shown rigorously). In fact, PA-consistency is equivalent in PA to the consistency scheme Con^S(PA) whether somebody likes it or not, and we have to prove Con^S(PA) in PA.

@SergeiArtemov The phrase "Try to justify your conclusion that Con(PA) is equivalent to 'PA is consistent' inside PA" seems problematic to me. Working inside PA, Con(PA) has a clear meaning. What is the meaning of 'PA is consistent'? How do you formalize this as an object PA can reason about? Declaring that it's Con(PA) or (a code for an enumeration of the schema) Con^S(PA), would be begging the question, so you must have some third option in mind?

The PA-consistency states, "no PA-derivation contains a line 0=1." The default technical step is Goedel numbering, which transliterates this into a semi-arithmetical form () "for all numerals n, n does not contain 0=1." PA has no quantifiers over n's, so there are two options. 1. Leave () as a scheme Con^S(PA), a series of formulas $\neg n:\bot$, $n=0,1,2,...$ mathematically equivalent to (*). 2. Use a quantifier over integers to end up with Con(PA), i.e., $\forall x(\neg x:\bot)$. Con(PA) is equivalent to Con^S(PA) in the standard model and not equivalent in PA: PA + Con^S(PA) |-/- Con(PA).

@SergeiArtemov Thank you for clarifying. Just Two more questions for you. (1) In your view, what is the proper way of interpreting Lagramge's Theorem (every natural number is a sum of four squares) in the context of PA? Should it be a single universally quantified sentence or a schema? (2) If it's a universally quantified sentence, what is the difference between the informal quantification over derivations in "PA is consistent" and the informal quantification over natural numbers in Lagrange's Theorem? I know it's a very basic question about your views. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

@AlexKruckman. By "natural numbers," mathematicians normally understand numerals 0,1,2, ... . Since PA does not have quantifiers over numerals, we have two options to make such F understandable for PA: (1) "quick and dirty," replace the quantifiers over numerals in F with the standard PA quantifiers. If PA proves the result F', then F also holds for numerals. If not, we are in limbo about whether F holds for numerals. (2) Honest but unexplored: present "for all n, G(n)" as a series of statements G(0), G(1), G(2), ... and try to make a mathematical sense out of it. I do this for Con(PA).

@SergeiArtemov So you also view a schematic representation of Lagrange's Theorem as more a more honest representation than the quantified version,  correct?

@AlexKruckman In this happy case, "quick and dirty" reading via PA quantifiers coincides with the "honest" one since the statement is provable. So, there is no practical sense in distinguishing them formally. Again, the quick-and-dirty approach fails when the sentence is true and unprovable. If it is proven, then you will get both readings.

@SergeiArtemov Interesting! So in your view, the question of whether $\forall n, \varphi(n)$ is an adequate formalization of "every natural number satisfies $\varphi$" in PA depends, to some degree, on whether $\forall n, \varphi(n)$ is in fact provable in PA.

@AlexKruckman. The adequate formalization of "every natural number satisfies $\varphi$" could be a scheme in the same way as the adequate description of water is "a bunch of H2O molecules"; true but not always relevant or helpful. The user should have enough common sense to choose the model. The scheme is correct but not always useful. The formula is easy to work with, and, in the case it is provable, it provides a correct answer. You can think of a counterexample that also settles the case. So, continue drinking water normally, but remember it is a bunch of H2O molecules.

@AlexKruckman. An in-depth answer. i) For general mathematicians, natural numbers are 0,1,2,.., which can be identified with numerals or standard model (s.m.) elements. So, "$F$ holds" means $F$ is true in s.m. ii) PA does not have quantifiers over numerals. There is no "direct" way to represent "$F$ holds" in PA. iii) PA is a tool to answer whether a property represented by an arithmetical formula $F$ holds (in s.m.): if PA proves $F$, then $F$ is true, and if PA proves $\neg F$, then $F$ is false. iv) If $F$ is independent, we must be creative, e.g. use schemes in case $\forall x G(x)$.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine. Your objections miss the point, sorry. 1) I do not try to "weakly" prove Con(PA) in PA and sell it as consistency proof. 2) This work does not try to reach the goals of Hilbert's Program. In (1), I argue that Con(PA) is the wrong way to arithmetize "PA is consistent": the latter uses numeral quantifiers, but the former - PA quantifiers. To represent numeral quantifiers, we have to use the scheme Con^S(PA). This leads to selector proofs. In (2), my work dismounts the unprovability of the consistency thesis and hence removes the roadblock in front of Hilbert's Program.

I'm primarily giving this answer to prevent a technical misconception from spreading further:
Artemov's notion of entailment, which I'll call "$\vdash_A$" here, is a bit more subtle than it may first appear. In order to say $T\vdash_A\varphi(x)$ (I'm adopting something between my preferred and Artemov's notation here), we need two things:

A primitive recursive function $p$ such that for each $n$, $p(n)$ is a (code for a) $T$-proof that $\varphi(n)$ holds.

A $T$-proof $\pi$ of the previous bulletpoint.


There are a couple natural ways we could weaken this - in particular, replace "p.r." with "$T$-provably total" or drop the requirement on $\pi$ - but either choice significantly alters the resulting notion. See in particular my vs. Emil Jerabek's answers at a recent question: if we drop the second bulletpoint then $\vdash_A$ for $\Pi^0_1$ consequents is just truth due to $\Sigma_1$-completeness, but if we keep it we wind up with $$\mathsf{PA}+Con(\mathsf{PA})\vdash Con(T)\quad\iff\quad \mathsf{PA}\vdash_A\chi_T(x)$$ (where $\chi_T$ is defined below).
Foundational concerns aside - and I personally am unconvinced by Artemov's arguments here - the precise definition of $\vdash_A$ he uses is carefully chosen and is not trivial.
That said ...
For $T$ "appropriate" let $\chi_T(x)$ be the (standardly-arithmetized) formula "$x$ is not a (code for a) proof of $\perp$ in $T$." Artemov's argument for $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash_A\chi_{\mathsf{PA}}(x)$$ uses a nontrivial fact about $\mathsf{PA}$, namely that it proves the consistency of each of its finite fragments. But this is completely unnecessary to the point of being misleading: in fact, any $T$ extending $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ has the analogous property $$T\vdash_A\chi_T(x).$$ The argument for this is quite simple:

On input $n$, first check whether $n$ is in fact a code for a $T$-proof of $\perp$.

If it is not, output the code $m$ for the verification of this.

If it is, we can find a slightly-longer $T$-proof of $\chi(n)$ by combining the proof coded by $n$ with ex falso. In this case we output the code $m'$ of that proof.


Since $\Delta_0$ facts can $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$-provably be checked "quickly," the above can be bundled together into an appropriate $(p,\pi)$-pair, and at no point have we used any reflection-type assumption on $T$.
Now I suspect that Artemov would at this point object as follows (quoting from page 7 of his above-linked paper, emphasis mine):

This is a rigorous contentual proof of the consistency of PA. Constructions and required properties used in this argument are formalizable in PA: partial truth definitions, compliance of truth definitions with PA-derivation rules, etc.

I suspect that Artemov would - correctly, in my opinion - claim that my argument above is non-contentual (due to the garbageness of the possible "second-case" proofs) but the reflection-based argument has real content. But I don't think this actually helps: we're still left with a situation where a new formal definition ($\vdash_A$) intended to capture some piece of mathematical intuition behaves trivially in a wide class of cases of interest. To me this is pretty fatal.
Of course this is not to say that $\vdash_A$ is not mathematically interesting or that Artemov's claims are technically false; I don't think either is the case. But I do think that the use of a higher-powered and less-broadly-applicable argument here makes $\vdash_A$ appear more significant than warranted.

This is a nice analysis of Artemov’s sense of “proving” a schema.  One thing I think usefully clarifies it further is to differentiate the outer and inner theories — to a notion one might notate as say $T_1 \vdash^{T_0} \varphi(x)$, to mean that there’s a p.r. function $f$ such that $T_0$ (the meta-theory) proves “$f$ provides proofs in $T_1$ (the object theory) of $\varphi(n)$, for each $n$”.  This in particular helps see that with the meta-theory $T_0$ fixed, the statement proven in $T_0$ cannot reasonably be read as “$T_1$ is consistent”, since it holds trivially for inconsistent $T_1$.

Your repeated example of a "simple consistency proof" above has been covered in section 5.2 of Artemov, Sergei. Serial Properties, Selector Proofs, and the Provability of Consistency. https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.12272v1. A consistency proof in PA is (1) a mathematical proof of consistency, which is (2) formalizable in PA. What you offer does not respect (1) since it is not proof of consistency (but something else); see the arxiv preprint.

@SergeiArtemov At this point I'm confused by your notion of $\widehat{PA}$ (and "contentual counterparts" in general - I don't find reference to "mathematical proof" any more clarifying). The only thing I am confident of right now is that for every c.e. theory $T$ extending $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$, there is a p.r. function $f$ such that $(i)$ for each $n$, $f(n)$ is a $T$-proof of "$n$ is not a $T$-proof of $\perp$" and $(ii)$ $T$ proves that fact $(i)$. So my first question is: do you agree with my claims (i) and (ii)? My second question is: if so, what exactly is $\widehat{PA}$?

(Maybe it will help to assume that I'm an extreme formalist, and moreover am dubious even of the consistency of $\mathsf{I\Sigma_2}$ or similar. Of course I'm not, but I think that will help clarify the definitions here.)

May I humbly ask you to read section 5.2 of my 2024 arxiv preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.12272v1 and, better yet, the whole text (about 20 pages of easy reading)? If you still have these questions standing, I will be more than happy to elaborate. In the informal arithmetic ˆ, there are some properties of reasonings - simple, natural, similar, etc. - which are not yet formalized and are used on a case-by-case basis. The notion of "proof of consistency" is one of them, and we have to apply our informal math judgments.

@SergeiArtemov I have read section 5.2 (and skimmed the whole text); my questions stand. I am rather confused by the extent to which informal reasoning is leaned on. E.g. is "formalized selector proof" an informal notion?

I am using "formalized" to represent "internalized," i.e., represented by a completely formal arithmetical object, like a formula or a term. I sense that your use of "formalized" is close to what I call "rigorous" with existing standards of mathematical rigor. This is a general observation. Shall we try to answer specific questions?

@SergeiArtemov OK. I suspect then that you do agree with my claims (i) and (ii) from a couple comments prior, but would say that that $f$ (+ its attendant data) is merely a $T$-"proof of the scheme" rather than a "selector proof in $\widehat{T}$" or similar. If that's right, my next question is: what exactly is $\widehat{PA}$?

$\widehat{PA}$ is what mathematicians call "elementary number theory," i.e., informal but rigorous reasoning based on FO logic, recursive definitions of p.r. operations, and the simple induction principle. I believe advanced high school kids (e.g., my Californian granddaughters) have a good grasp of it. $\widehat{PA}$ is related to $\textsf{PA}$ by the formalization principle (similar to the Church Thesis) that any rigorous reasoning in $\widehat{PA}$ can be internalized as a derivation in $\textsf{PA}$.

@SergeiArtemov OK, so suppose I didn't accept all of elementary number theory, and in particular were already suspicious about the formal consistency of $\mathsf{I\Sigma_2}$. How should I interpret your results? (In fact I'm not so skeptical, but I am extremely suspicious of hard-to-remove informalities.)

E.g. my doppelganger in the previous comment has no trouble interpreting (say) Martin's proof of Borel determinacy in ZFC; he just says "OK, you have (made a compelling argument that there is) a formal derivation in ZFC of (the formalization of) Borel determinacy." My doppelganger suspects that this result will eventually be trivialized (by the realization that ZFC is in fact inconsistent), but doesn't doubt that a deduction has been produced (modulo formalization details :P). But I don't see how to similarly interpret anything that refers to $\widehat{PA}$.

This is quite unusual. Generally, people find elementary arithmetic easier to accept than ZFC. An old and useful advice is to try to work with it, and then you'll get used to it. Please focus on the points you understand and do not try to grasp them all simultaneously.  Having some study groups helps, especially if you are the instructor. I will be glad to answer specific questions.

@SergeiArtemov "Generally, people find elementary arithmetic easier to accept than ZFC." This conflates accepts as true (or consistent or similar) with understands precisely what it means. ZFC is less likely to be true(/etc.), but is vastly more precisely defined (read: is actually precisely defined) than $\widehat{\mathsf{PA}}$ = elementary number theory.

Ultimately I'm not interested in results about/in ill-defined systems, so I'm trying to pin down how your results can be made formal (or if you prefer, "symbolic"). That's my specific question: can you phrase "$PA$ can selector-prove (or whatever) its own consistency but $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ cannot" in a computer-understandable way?

@NoahSchweber. Foundations are full of ill-defined notions, and we have to deal with this fact: finitistic methods (Hilbert), the so-called 24th Hilbert Problem, etc. There has not been a formal criterion of the right consistency formalization (cf. Rosser's consistency and others), and logicians have lived in this situation for decades. There is no criterion for what formal proof of a not-yet-formalized property is. The consistency proofs are in this category: you know it when you see it. However, the core examples may be convincing despite the absence of a complete umbrella formalization.

I appreciate your interest in this work. The paper Serial properties, selector proofs and the provability of consistency passed a rigorous refereeing and has been accepted to JLC. I have just approved the proofs, and the paper will appear on the JLC website shortly. I promised not to publish the full text before that (though I am open to answering questions about Arxiv preprints).
July 27 addition: The paper published in JLC: Sergei Artemov. Serial properties, selector proofs and the provability of consistency. Journal of Logic and Computation, https://doi.org/10.1093/logcom/exae034, Published: 26 July 2024. (Ask me if you have trouble downloading the paper from JLC.)
Abstract. The consistency of a theory means that each of its formal derivations $D_0, D_1, D_2,\ldots$ is free of contradictions. For Peano Arithmetic $\textsf{PA}$, after the standard coding of derivations by numerals, $\textsf{PA}$-consistency is directly represented by the consistency scheme $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$, which is a series of arithmetical statements "$n$ is not a code of a derivation of $(0=1)$" for numerals $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$ . We note that the consistency formula $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$, $\forall x$ "$x$ is not a code of a derivation of $(0=1)$" is strictly stronger in $\textsf{PA}$ than $\textsf{PA}$-consistency and corresponds to some other property which we call "uniform consistency." When studying the provability of consistency in $\textsf{PA}$, we should work not with the consistency formula $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ but with the consistency scheme $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$, which adequately represents $\textsf{PA}$ consistency.
This paper introduces the Hilbert-inspired notion of proof of an infinite series of formulas in a theory and proves $\textsf{PA}$-consistency in the form $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ in $\textsf{PA}$. These findings show that $\textsf{PA}$ proves its consistency, whereas, by Goedel's second incompleteness theorem, $\textsf{PA}$ cannot prove its uniform consistency.
Comments for the OF readers.

Picking $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ to represent the consistency of $\textsf{PA}$ has been a strengthening fallacy. $\textsf{PA}$-consistency as a property of formal derivations is fairly represented by the scheme $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$, which is a property of numerals. The formula $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ is strictly stronger in $\textsf{PA}$ than the $\textsf{PA}$-consistency. So, the (un)provability of consistency analysis based on $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ is void, and we ought to consider $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ instead. This is not a matter of taste or aesthetic preferences but rather a solid mathematical necessity.

To analyze the provability of consistency, we need to agree on what counts as proof of a serial property, here $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$, in $\textsf{PA}$. The paper offers a complete account of the choices and argues in favor of the one endorsed by Hilbert in the 1920s, which we call selector proofs. There is not much freedom here, either: selector proofs have been tacitly used in mathematics, and the time is ripe to formalize them officially.

The rest is a standard proof theoretical treatment of $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ with a modest technical contribution that the selector based on partial truth definitions an easily formalizable p.r. function.


A special comment for people who believe in $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ in the context of provability in $\textsf{PA}$: $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ is the wrong way to represent $\textsf{PA}$ consistency. If you try to check why $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ is equivalent to $\textsf{PA}$ consistency, you would need to refer to the standard model of $\textsf{PA}$ or similar notions requiring strong meta-assumptions that defeat the purpose of analyzing the provability of consistency in $\textsf{PA}$.
The right way to represent consistency property (which is a property of finite derivation strings) arithmetically is by a serial property/scheme $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$, which is a series of claims "$n$ is consistent" for numerals $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$. It is immediate that "$\textsf{PA}$ is consistent" is equivalent to $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ without any metamathematical assumptions about $\textsf{PA}$. Furthermore, it is easy to check that $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ is strictly stronger than $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ in $\textsf{PA}$ which makes Goedel's result about the unprovability of $\mathrm{Con}(\textsf{PA})$ not directly applicable to $\textsf{PA}$ consistency (which is equivalent to $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ in $\textsf{PA}$).

Welcome to MathOverflow, Prof. Artemov! I guess JLC = Journal of Logic and Computation?

I took the liberty of nicely formatting your text, and fixing a small conflict between the Markdown syntax and what one is used to from (La)TeX. Thank you for the clarification regarding the status of your paper. This is indeed very interesting.

Welcome to MathOverflow, Sergei.

I have a very naive question. Intuitively, this means that you put the "for all n" outside the statement defining consistency. So the serial property $Con^S(PA)$ has no Gödel numbering. Is it correct ?

Welcome to MO! I have a question, which perhaps I can post as a separate MO question if your answer is too long for a comment. You mention Hilbert's program. As I understand it, Hilbert hoped for a PRA proof of the consistency of a set-theoretic system such as ZF. With your proposed definition of "consistency," what are the prospects for that?

Thank you! Your question makes perfect sense (except for the weird "your proposed definition of "consistency""; it is the common definition of consistency used by Hilbert). In short, my work dismounts the unprovability of consistency thesis (that a consistent theory cannot prove its own consistency), removing the principal obstacle for Hilbert's Program. This is our humble contribution.

To Philippe Gaucher. A special class of serial properties generated by some arithmetical formula F(x) is called "schemes." They have perfectly well-defined Goedel numbers. Example: the consistency scheme $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ is generated by the formula $\neg x:\bot$.

@SergeiArtemov I suspect Philippe was asking if $\mathrm{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ had a single Gödel number, or not. With the "for all $n$" outside the statement it seems like it should have a sequence of Gödel numbers, one for each $n$. But this is only my naive reading.

This is correct. But with a bit deeper coding, we can get away with a single numeral code. Since $\textsf{Con}^S(\textsf{PA})$ is defined by its formula $\neg (x:\bot)$, the Godel number of the latter may be regarded as a code of the whole scheme. It all depends on what we want to do with the codes.

@SergeiArtemov I have now posted my question, which you said makes perfect sense, as a separate MO question.

Santos, Sieg, and Kahle have a published paper building on Artemov's paper. They argue for a similar position and discuss its relation with Hilbert's program.
Paulo Guilherme Santos, Wilfried Sieg, Reinhard Kahle, A new perspective on completeness and finitist consistency, Journal of Logic and Computation, 2023;, exad021, https://doi.org/10.1093/logcom/exad021

I have waited for Noah Schweber to correct his above presentation of my work after we had a meaningful exchange in which Noah seemed to understand (does not mean to accept) my definitions and constructions. Now, the time is up, and, whereas Noah himself stopped producing his arguments and conclusions, his comment still stands unaltered and, unfortunately, spreads misunderstanding.
In my work, there are several interrelated but different constructions involved in the consistency proof.

A selector proof of a serial property ${F_0,F_1,F_2,...}$ in $T$, reasonably well presented by Noah Schweber: it is a pair of

(i) a selector $s(n)$ such that for each $n$, $s(n)$ is a $T$-proof of $F_n$ and
(ii) a proof in $T$ that (i) always works.
This notion applies to both formal and contentual theories. Noah Schweber's comment duly mentions the necessity of (ii).

A consistency proof (in ${\sf PA}$, for short) is

A. a mathematical selector proof of consistency of ${\sf PA}$ such that each $s(n)$ yields a contextual (mathematical) proof that $n$ is not a proof of $0=1$ in ${\sf PA}$;
B. a formalization of (A) in ${\sf PA}$.
This corresponds to Hilbert's approach: a consistency proof in $T$ is a mathematical proof of consistency, and this proof is formalized in $T$.
The difference between a selector proof of the consistency scheme and a selector proof of consistency property was explicitly discussed in both arXiv preprint 2024 and JLC_2024 paper, section 5.2, with exactly the same example as given by Noah Schweber. I am puzzled how, after all these materials, somebody could publicly claim a "more general and much easier" proof of the consistency property by just repeating the example given in Section 5.2 with a warning to avoid it.
Here is a specific misrepresentation. I am applying a traditional (and nontrivial) proof-theoretical technique to prove the $\sf PA$ consistency in $\sf PA$ (which is much more than just proving consistency scheme ${\sf Con}^S({\sf PA})$ in $\sf PA$ formally). Noah Schweber instead presents a well-known solution of a different and much easier task of proving ${\sf Con}^S({\sf PA})$ in $\sf PA$ formally. This trick has nothing to do with my results of proving consistency at all.
A friendly piece of advice: this work is quite subtle, and many "obvious" versions of it are plain wrong. Read the paper by yourself: https://doi.org/10.1093/logcom/exae034,

Prof Artemov, I appreciate your patience and dedication in explaining your work, but please be aware that MathOverflow is not a general discussion forum, but designed to be a fairly rigid Q&A platform, with scope for brief, contained discussion in comments to clarify answers and questions, and sometimes other constructive comments. People can hopefully keep your explanatory comments here in mind when they go to read your paper, but with my moderator's hat on I respectfully request that we let the matter rest here for now. I hope you understand the need to run a tight ship online.

That said, I am extremely interested and rather excited about your paper. I was describing it to the bright young teenager that I tutor, since he knows about Gödel's incompleteness result. But I had to confess that my impressions are as-yet brief, since my other, main, day job doesn't permit me the freedom to drop everything and study it.
